# Blank Canvas with labels at the top with strikethrough on them when using chart.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I have the following code that is attempting to display a summary of the most popular forms as defined by the number of inserted rows in their respective database tables and display this as a pie chart via chart.js 2.8.

```php
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="FormsSubmitted" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="FormsSubmitted-tab">
        <div>
            <canvas class="my-4 w-100" style="height: 100%;" id="popforms"></canvas>
        </div>
            
        
        <?php
        // query to get the number of rows for each table with prefix "prism_formdata_"
        $GetFormPopularityQuery = "SELECT REPLACE(table_name, 'prism_formdata_', '') AS form_name, table_rows AS num_rows 
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'general' AND table_name LIKE 'prism_formdata_%';";
        // execute the query and get the result
        $GetFormPopularityResult = $mysqli->query($GetFormPopularityQuery);

        // create an empty array to hold the chart data
        $data = array('labels' => array(), 'datasets' => array(array('data' => array())));

        
        // loop through the result and add the data to the chart array
        while ($GetFormPopularityRow = $GetFormPopularityResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data['labels'][] = $GetFormPopularityRow['form_name'];
            $data['datasets'][0]['data'][] = $GetFormPopularityRow['num_rows'];
        }
        $labellist = array();
        foreach($labellist as $key -> $value){
            $labellist[] = '\''.$value.'\'';
        }
        $labellist = implode(',',$labellist);
        echo $labellist;
        // convert the chart data to JSON format
        $json_data = json_encode($data);
        //num of rows uses to calculate chart colors in script below.
        $formscount = mysqli_num_rows($GetFormPopularityResult);
        ?>
        <script>
            //when the page/files have finished loading...
            window.onload = function() {

                $(window).resize(function() {
                    popforms.resize();
                });

            // Set the colors to be used for the chart pie segments.
            var colors = ['rgba(76, 18, 161, 1)', 'rgba(229, 0, 109, 1)', 'rgba(205, 216, 223, 1)', 'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.8)', 'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.8)', 'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.8)', 'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.6)', 'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.6)', 'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.6)', 'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.4)', 'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.4)', 'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.4)', 'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.2)', 'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.2)', 'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.2)'];
            var bgColors = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo $formscount;?>; i++) {
                    bgColors.push(colors[i % colors.length]);  
                }
                
                // get the chart data from PHP script
                var chart_data = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;
                //get the chart labels from the PHP script
                //var labellist = <?php //echo $labellist; ?> //didnt work

                // create a new pie chart
                console.table('bgColors is: '+bgColors);
                console.dir(chart_data);
                var ctx = document.getElementById('popforms').getContext('2d');
                var popforms = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Form Popularity',
                            data: chart_data,
                            backgroundColor: bgColors // Use the array of colors
                        }],
                        labels: chart_data.labels // Use the labels from the chart data
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true
                    }
                                            });
                                        }

        </script>
    </div>
```

It almost seems to work, but the canvas is empty save for the labels which are displaying at the top correctly, with the correct colors and names, but the text for each label has a strikethrough effect on it.

If I look in the browser console, I can see my debugging is showing that the chart_data is there and looks like what I think is an expected format and looks something like this:

```
datasets
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
data
: 
(20) ['35', '0', '2', '14', '8', '13', '0', '0', '2', '4', '0', '4', '4', '0', '0', '2', '0', '4', '34', '4']
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
labels
: 
(20) [<list of strings in a comma separated list, each enclosed in a single quote here, removed because I don't want to publicly show the data.>]
pop
: 
ƒ ()
push
: 
ƒ ()
shift
: 
ƒ ()
splice
: 
ƒ ()
unshift
: 
ƒ ()
_chartjs
: 
{listeners: Array(1)}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Chart.js is version 2.8 and is being loaded on the page correctly, I know this because the chart worked until I starting trying to add the colors to the chart segments/labels, so I may have messed up something with the syntax there, but I can't see what it is.

Note: My code is a combination of examples, searching Stackoverflow/Google and Chartjs docs, but I admit I'm not 100% fluent in it all. You will probably notice a few lines for debugging purposes in there that are also not 100% necessary at this point.

Comment: The data seems to be strings, not numbers. Try `data: chart_data.map(parseFloat)`

Comment: I replaced with `data: chart_data.map(parseFloat),` Just below the "label: 'Form Popularity'," line and this makes the canvas totally blank and produced a console error: "TypeError: chart_data.map is not a function".

Comment: I can't really understand the data you posted from the console. Maybe you can a just post the result of a `console.log(chart_data);`. Even better, you can add the source html+javascript as it is seen from the browser "view page source", since it is the code after the php has been executed and thus can be reproduced by everyone, since we don't have access to your database results

Comment: After taking a step back then returning to this, I think I've realized what the problem is. The PHP code has been crafted to specifically format the chart_data in a way ready to put it into the data: line in the chart creation. Tryign to then add the colors to it resulted in me altering the syntax to include the color declaration, which breaks it because the chart_data is no longer inserted into the javascript with the correct syntax. The answer is  to instead add the color data to the array in the while loop in the PHP and leave the data as `data: chart_data,`

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, the solution was to put the colors into the PHP while loop so that when the chart_Data is inserted into the the javascript part, it already contains the color instructions in the correct format.

```php
        //the relevant part of the PHP code
      
        // define an array of colors
        $colors = array(
            'rgba(76, 18, 161, 1)', 
            'rgba(229, 0, 109, 1)', 
            'rgba(205, 216, 223, 1)', 
            'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.8)', 
            'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.8)', 
            'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.8)', 
            'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.6)', 
            'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.6)', 
            'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.6)', 
            'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.4)', 
            'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.4)', 
            'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.4)', 
            'rgba(76, 18, 161, 0.2)', 
            'rgba(229, 0, 109, 0.2)', 
            'rgba(205, 216, 223, 0.2)'
        );

        // set a counter variable for cycling through the colors array
        $color_counter = 0;

        // create an empty array to hold the chart data
        $data = array('labels' => array(), 'datasets' => array(array('data' => array())));

        
        // loop through the result and add the data to the chart array
        while ($GetFormPopularityRow = $GetFormPopularityResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data['labels'][] = $GetFormPopularityRow['form_name'];
            $data['datasets'][0]['data'][] = $GetFormPopularityRow['num_rows'];
            $data['datasets'][0]['backgroundColor'][] = $colors[$color_counter % count($colors)];
            $color_counter++;
        }
```

And the bit where we use the chart_data in the javascript

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('popforms').getContext('2d');
                var popforms = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: chart_data,
                    options: {
                        responsive: true
                    }
                                            });
                                        }
```